# Why does my program not enter handler mode under GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, mode, keil

I have this code which works under KEIL but not under GCC and I do not know why is this happening. It tests some of RTX OS functionality.

Handler:

```
void GenWait_IRQHandler (void) {

  switch (ISR_ExNum) {
    case 0: Stat_Isr = osDelay (10); break;
  #if (osFeatureWait)
    case 1: Stat_Isr = osWait  (10); break;
  #endif
  }
}
```

The above code is entered by setting pending IRQ from main:

```
...
ISR_ExNum = 0; /* Test: osDelay */
NVIC_SetPendingIRQ((IRQn_Type)SWI_HANDLER);
ASSERT_TRUE (Stat_Isr == osErrorISR);
...
```

The problem is that this `ASSERT_TRUE()` fails because `Stat_Isr` is not equal to `osErrorISR` which it should be as calling `osDelay()` is not allowed from Handler mode:

```
osStatus osDelay (uint32_t millisec) {
  if (__get_IPSR() != 0U) {
    return osErrorISR;                          // Not allowed in ISR
  }
  return __svcDelay(millisec);
}
```

As I said when compiled under KEIL it works fine but when compiled under GCC it fails. It looks like IPSR is not updated when entering handler and `osDelay()` does not know it should return error. Any idea why is this happening ?

`SWI_Handler` is software handler, and I call `GenWait_IRQHandler()` in it.

EDIT:

This is implementation available from KEIL Packs as RTX validation, I just try to make it work on chip I am working with. So it should work even if I call functions from ISR.

Moreover as I wrote in comment:

(from www.keil.com):

> Interrupt Service Routines (ISR) can call some CMSIS-RTOS functions. When a CMSIS-RTOS function cannot be called from ISR context, it rejects the invocation.

And then:

> Functions that cannot be called from an ISR are verifying the interrupt status and return, in case they are called from an ISR context, the status code `osErrorISR`. In some implementations, this condition might be caught using the HARD FAULT vector.

EDIT2:

Reducing optimization from -O3 to -O1 fixed isse but I still do not know why it was optimized like this and how I can easily prevent compiler from doing this. I know that simplest answer is to add couple of "volatile's" but this is not this simple in this case, I think.

Comment: Are you sure it's safe to call OS-functions in an interrupt handler?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is as I expect it to return error.

Comment: Look for differences in the assembly generated by the compilers.  Are `ISR_ExNum` and `Stat_Isr` declared as volatile?  Are compiler optimizations disabled for both tool chains?

Comment: @EOF totally agree. Most of embedded OS doesn't manage IRQ. And when you are inside a IRQ, Sheduler is often automatically disable (because based on an IRQ of lower priority). Only use OS function which are clearly design to be call inside an handler

Comment: Assuming that misuse of functions inside an IRQ will return an error is extremely unwise.  In most embedded settings, and indeed the majority of all programming environments historically, it has been up to the programmer to determine the validity of what they are trying to do.  Automatic protections against programmer mistakes are a recent thing, very environment dependent, and not something you should be in the habit of relying on at all.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help me. First, my question was why it does not work under GCC while works under KEIL compiler. Second (from www.keil.com):
" Interrupt Service Routines (ISR) can call some CMSIS-RTOS functions. When a CMSIS-RTOS function cannot be called from ISR context, it rejects the invocation."

And then:

"Functions that cannot be called from an ISR are verifying the interrupt status and return, in case they are called from an ISR context, the status code osErrorISR. In some implementations, this condition might be caught using the HARD FAULT vector."

Comment: So it looks like RTX supports calling OS functions from ISR.

@kkrambo ISR_ExNum and Stat_Isr are defined as volatile. I will check for the optimalization level of GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @kkrambo for the right trail. The problem was with instructions order. Adding volatiles to `Stat_Isr` was not enough but adding memory barrier made this work for me:

```
...
ISR_ExNum = 0; /* Test: osDelay */
NVIC_SetPendingIRQ((IRQn_Type)SWI_HANDLER);
__DMB();
ASSERT_TRUE (Stat_Isr == osErrorISR);
...
```

It happend because code optimalization made ISR to be called after `ASSERT_TRUE (Stat_Isr == osErrorISR);`. I think this is clear now.